# Unicorn error : Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, bundle, unicorn

I am a beginner about setup VPS for rails app,
to start I am trying Nginx + Unicorn with Digital Ocean as provider (specifically the One Click install https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean) .

I configured all the environment (unicorn.conf, nginx.conf, capistrano, git, ... ) quite easily, but now I am stuck in an error.

The log file **/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log** is continuously getting this error (therefore it is grooowing) :

> E, [2014-10-19T19:09:24.117472 #24110] ERROR -- : Could not find
>   rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
>   `block in materialize'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in`
>   map!'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
>   `materialize'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in`
>   specs'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in
>   `specs_for'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in`
>   requested_specs'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in
>   `requested_specs'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in`
>   setup'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:121:in
>   `setup'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
>   `require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`
>   rescue in require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in
>   `require'
>   /var/www/inphrase/releases/20141018133126/config/boot.rb:4:in`'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   /var/www/inphrase/releases/20141018133126/config/application.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   /var/www/inphrase/releases/20141018133126/config/environment.rb:2:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require' config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   instance_eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `initialize' config.ru:1:in`new' config.ru:1:in `<main>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in`
>   eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in
>   `block in builder'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in`
>   call'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in
>   `build_app!'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:628:in`
>   init_worker_process'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:651:in
>   `worker_loop'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in`
>   spawn_missing_workers'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:536:in
>   `maintain_worker_count'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in`
>   join'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in
>   `<top (required)>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in`
>   load' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in ...

I've run already **Bundle install** in the folder's app in the server, and all gems has been installed successfully, so why I get the infamous **Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)** ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different rubies. Bundler installs Rake in one gemset, Rails is looking in another. See the bottom of the stack trace:

> load' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ **ruby-2.1.3** /bin/unicorn:23:in '
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ **ruby-2.0.0-p353** /bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ **ruby-2.0.0-p353** /bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in ...

Set a default Ruby version to use:

```
rvm use --default 2.1.3
```

Open your Gemfile and specify a matching Ruby version

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.3'
# ...
```

Then run `bundle install` again.